# Rendering what's in viewport

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I am trying to animate what shows up in the viewport moving around in wireframe mode. I would like to keep the vertex highlighting 'look' (in edit mode wireframe) while panning around the camera. Can anyone advise how to accomplish this? I can render in 'wireframe' but I can't get the vertex highlighting texture.

Thanks

[image: the effect I'm going for]

Answer (score 13):

This can be done using [OpenGL render](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/opengl.html) while in edit mode. Click the buttons in the header, or *Info > Render > OpenGL Render*:

[image]

Result:

[image]